# How to fill missing timestamp values along x axis in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to fill missing values along an x-axis on a plot using ggplot. Currently, various ticks along the x-axis are truncated, missing intervals where the associated y axis value is equal to 0.

Sorry there's no script here, but currently, the ticks along the x-axis are spaced at 15-minute intervals with 2 missing ticks - i.e. in two locations, the ticks increase by 30 minutes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You probably want to look at `scale_x_datetime` or `scale_x_continuous`, depending on how your data looks. But please provide data samples, your script and what the actual desired result is

Comment: "Sorry there's no script here". But why not? It's hard to help you debug code we can't see. I'm sure that if you posted your code, someone would be able to help solve the problem ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = publish_time, y = views)) + 
    geom_line()+
    scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq.POSIXt(a, b, 900))
```

To use `scale_x_datetime` and have the subsequent `breaks` work successfully you want to make sure you `x` is a `POSIXt` object type. `900` in the above code is because `seq.POSIXt(a,b,by=c)`expects `c` to be:

- A number, taken to be in seconds.
- A object of class difftime
- A character string, containing one of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month", "quarter" or "year". This can optionally be preceded by a (positive or negative) integer and a space, or followed by "s".

Since you asked for 15 minutes interval, that's 900 seconds.